# How to halt a series of tasks but continue watching files in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a `Gulp` task that lints Javascript files before injecting them into a HTML page. I'd like the files not to be injected if a linting error is found. So if an error appears in the first task, cancel all subsequent tasks.

The caveat is that this task is run by `gulp.watch` and I'd like the watch to continue to monitor the files and inject them if the linting errors are resolved.

Is this possible in `gulp`? Plugins are acceptable.

`Gulpfile` below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

//(plugin declarations removed for brevity)

gulp.task('eslint', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.lint)
  .pipe($.cached('eslint'))
  .pipe($.eslint())
  .on('error', $.gutil.log)
  .pipe($.eslint.format());
});

gulp.task('inject:resources', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.src.templates)
  .pipe(
    $.inject(gulp.src(config.dist.scripts + '/all*.js',
    {read: false}),
      {
        ignorePath: config.dist.public,
        addRootSlash: false,
        name: 'scripts'
      }
  ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.public));
});

gulp.task('watch:js', function(callback) {
  runSequence('eslint', 'inject:resources');
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(config.src.scripts, ['watch:js']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make `eslint` fail when any of your files produces an error. You can do that by placing [`eslint.failAfterError()`](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#eslintfailaftererror) at the end of your stream:

```
gulp.task('eslint', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.lint)
  .pipe($.cached('eslint'))
  .pipe($.eslint())
  .on('error', $.gutil.log)
  .pipe($.eslint.format())
  .pipe($.eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

When your `eslint` task fails the subsequent `inject:resources` task will not be executed by `runSequence`.

Next you need to  make the `callback` in your `watch:js` task available to `runSequence`, otherwise gulp will not notice when `watch:js` has finished (and since you can't run the same task in parallel with itself this would effectively prevent `watch:js` from being started again):

```
gulp.task('watch:js', function(callback) {
  runSequence('eslint', 'inject:resources', callback);
});
```

The only downside to this is that the above will produce an ugly stack trace that doesn't really provide any useful additional info. If you want to prevent that you can just "swallow" the error that is being passed up the callback chain like this:

```
gulp.task('watch:js', function(callback) {
  runSequence('eslint', 'inject:resources', function(err) {
    callback();
  });
});
```